# Salesforce Certification got expired.

Tags: certification

My PD1 Certification got expired today morning. I forget to wrote the maintenance exam. Is their any possibility to write maintenance exam and retain the PD1 Certification. Or I have to wrote PD1 Certification exam once again to get it. Please help me on this.

Comment: You need to write the exam once again.

Answer (score 6):

**When your certification is expired you have to give certification exam again by paying full exam fee i.e $200.**

For more information about certification expiration read this:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Information-about-Certification-Expiration